# Why will I have link errors when invoking a library (building the library is successful) in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll

I have a question related to invoking a C++ library. The compilation of the library is successful. After that, the library is invoked by a normal executable program. However, several link errors occur.I give an example to illustrate my problem.

I have download an old version of TIFF library (version 3.6.1) and then compiled it to a static library: `tiff.lib`. After that I wrote an executable program for reading and writing TIFF files by invoking the library. However, the following errors appear:

```
 2>tiff.lib(tif_jpeg.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __TIFFmalloc
2>tiff.lib(tif_lzw.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __TIFFmalloc
2>tiff.lib(tif_dirinfo.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __TIFFmalloc
2>tiff.lib(tif_luv.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __TIFFmalloc
2>tiff.lib(tif_pixarlog.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __TIFFmalloc
2>tiff.lib(tif_zip.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __TIFFmalloc
2>tiff.lib(tif_dirwrite.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __TIFFmalloc
2>tiff.lib(tif_write.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __TIFFmalloc
2>tiff.lib(tif_dirread.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __TIFFmalloc
```

I cannot understand why I will receive link errors as `tiff.lib` has been built successfully and it has also been linked successfully by my executable program. If something wrong with `tiff.lib`, I expect the link errors should appear during the compilation and link procedure when building the lib. Any ideas will be appreciated!

EDIT: I add some details in order to find the solution. `tiff.lib` is built as a static library, and when I use `dumpbin.exe /exports tiff.lib` to display all definitions exported in the library, the following message is given:

```
Dump of file tiff.lib

File Type: LIBRARY

  Summary

         3B8 .bss
        9405 .data
       D5640 .debug$S
         C38 .debug$T
         C4E .drectve
       19E79 .rdata
          84 .rtc$IMZ
          84 .rtc$TMZ
       3363E .text
```

It seems that no symbols are exported.

Comment: http://maptools-org.996276.n3.nabble.com/linker-problem-td1964.html

Comment: @H2CO3 Thanks, I have checked. The library and the executable program share the same function calling conversion _cdecl(/Gd). However, the same errors occur.

Comment: How are you calling your compiler to build and link the executable? By the way, it seems that you are having problems with TIFFmalloc function. Are you sure that this function is in your lib?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the discussions, I have come to realize that my program's error lies in the fact that some functions have not been defined correctly. It may happen that in some libraries the function may be declared in the head file with the keyword "`extern`". However, the implementation of the function is defined in another file, which could be excluded when building the library. Function calling conversion, as explained by @praks411, is another scenario, which you should consider when you meet with the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

I think tiff.lib is C library and you are linking in c++. So I guess you will need to use extern "C" to include its header .h file.

```
extern "C"
{
  #include<tiff.h>
}
```

Something like that above is just example. Also make sure you are setting correct calling convention in project property page of your c++ project

```
C/C++ ----------> Advanced ---------->Call Convention--->_cdecl(/Gd) //Set only if required

C/C++----------->Advanced------------>Compile As----->C++ Code(/TP)
```

Comment: Thanks, and I have done as you suggested. However, still the same errors exist.

Comment: This is strange. May be you can use dumpbin.exe on libtiff from vc++ command line to check whether the above unresolved symbol is actually present in lib or not. Also look into fatih_k's link.

Comment: I think I have found something that may be the reason why I have the problem. I use dumpbin.exe /exports tiff.lib to all definitions exported from the static tiff library. However, it seems that there are no exported symbols.

Comment: So were you able to resolve the issue? I would also recommend to you to use dumpbin.exe /SYMBOLS to check if TIFFmalloc is there or not. I'm wondering how you are able to build tifflib is TIFFmalloc is not there. Also check if you are not including #include<tiff.h> somewhere else in your project. If it is the case then you may have to put extern "C" there also.